# Save data from combobox only stored in one word, the next word is not stored

Tags: php, mysql

Want to ask ya, there is the problem of time insert data from combobox the data is comboboxnya dynamic, so time insert data from combobox that we select hanya1 words like "New" safe, well but the time if we choose who is more than one word eg "New York ", well that is to insert into the database only the word" New "alone who palembangnya not come to save, how ya think" solution.

The script below:

```
<Form method = "post" action = "">
<Select name = "city"> <? Php

require_once ('../ library / koneksi.php');
$ Result = "SELECT * FROM city";
$ Query = mysql_query ($ result);
while ($ row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($ query)) {
$ City = $ row ['city'];
echo "<option value = $ city> $ city </ option>";
}
?> </ Select>
<Input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Save">
</ Form>

<? Php
if (isset ($ _ POST ['submit'])) {
$ City = $ _ POST ['city'];
$ Insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO city (city) values ('$ city')");
}
?>
```

Comment: are you sure this code even work with all of the spaces there?

Comment: I've tried it, the problem now is the data that is displayed on the dynamic dombobox drawn directly from the database, and when the data is stored, which is stored only in the beginning just words such as "New York" is stored only said New alone.

Comment: I remember you posted this earlier and deleted the question. TBH, I had no idea what you were asking then and I still have no idea now. Plus, Your code contains a lot of spaces where there shouldn't be any, yet did not contain spaces in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the attribute value.

```
echo "<option value ='$city'>$city </ option>";
```

You also need to fix your spacing issues, update your DB driver (PDO or mysqli), and start using parameterized queries.

This is wide open to SQL injections (or rather this bit)

```
$Insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO city (city) values ('$city')");
```

Comment: which is what I wanted to post in their deleted answer, but feared a deep rabbit hole. Sure hope it won't be.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got some extra dirt, I can fill the hole in quickly.

Comment: I've a pretty good spade and flashlight if you need some help ;-)